# Facebook api can access password protected website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if facebook's api can access a website protected by htaccess password ?

Because I need to try some opengraph plugins I did.

thanks

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use a domain I own in order to test an application I wrote. But I don't want anyone to be able to access the website, despite me. I remember that I protected a website with htpasswd, and the facebook connect api worked, so it might be able to access the website if it's protected like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work because your server will be accessing the API, but the API won't be accessing your server. You can also run your app in sandbox mode.